# How to run commands on CentOS reboot

Tags: linux, centos, centos7

I want to run the following commands one after the other upon reboot of the server after I do `shutdown -r now` but not sure how to do it:

- ## getenforce
- ## setenforce 0
- ## systemctl start httpd.service

I'm running CentOS 7.x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you can crontab it

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and add the line

```
@reboot /somewhere/myscript.sh
```

and put the 3 commands in the myscript.sh with the proper rights.

But it is a bad idea since you can you just make these changes permanent:

```
systemctl enable httpd
```

and

```
vim /etc/selinux/config
```

to set the SELINUX variable to permissive

This will make the configuration permanent across reboot.

Comment: @ZacRam I edit my answer. You should not need to run automatically these commands after reboot

Comment: Hi @ZacRam if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. If not let me know. thanks